# Enable 32-bit apps on 64-bit Azure Web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We are looking at deploying our website to Azure. It will mainly be a 64-bit web app, but it will make use of some 32-bit DLLs.

In IIS, you can enable an App Pool to 'Enable 32-bit Applications'. We cannot see how to do the same on an Azure Web App. Can we? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) needs to either be 32 bit or 64 bit. If it's 64 bit, I don't think there is anything you can do to load 32 bit DLLs in it.

When you set 'Enable 32-bit Applications' in IIS, your entire worker process becomes 32 bit. This is the equivalent of choosing the bitness of an Azure Web App. Note that Azure Web Apps are 32 bits by default. Since you need to load 32 bit DLLs, you should not try to use a 64 bits worker process.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I am having serious problem with that assumption. I have an app that depends on a 32-bit native dll, my app service is set to 32 bit and I get a crash. I had the same problem with my local IIS, and when I modified my local app pool to allow 32-bit I got it working locally. I still can't get it to work on Azure.